# ACTION_SEND used to send sms

Tags: android, android-activity, sms

I want to open native application to send sms but there should be already phone number. I found ACTION_SEND but when I'm calling my function it's return error that:

```
04-26 11:59:15.991: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20198): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO (has extras) }
```

My code presented here:

```
    private void smsSend(String number) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, null);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, number);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I know that's is simple but I don't know why it does not work and I can not find any helfull information.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Why, this should work fine. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO

Check out my code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");   
startActivity(it);
```

Comment: If one is using [markiz's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/618661/markiz-lonkly) code outside of an activity, one can put it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_NEW_ACTIVITY_TASK); I did use it like that, so thought it might just be useful. :)

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:");  to open messages only not sent automatically to any number

Comment: OMG, that's pretty much of necroposting, @mostafahashim

Comment: I just added it to any person needs it @Lonkly

Comment: Good this worked, added an extra line to allow sending to multiple receivers. `code`  it.putExtra ("address", new String ("078544467777;0745558766"));

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the following code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

//use to fill the sms body
StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder("sms:" + mobilenumber);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
sendIntent.setData("");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I think this may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the info !
Here is my solution using the previous info:

```
if (url.indexOf("tel:") > -1) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
    return true;
}
else if (url.indexOf("sms:") > -1){
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url)));
    return true;
}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, the intent without uri parameter work for all devices, 
except for Pixel Phone where I need to use it, so I check the 2 ways:

```
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    final Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    final String phoneNumber = "1234567890";
    final String msg = "Hello!";
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", msg);
    smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    final PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(smsIntent, 0);
    if (infos.size() <1) {
        //No Application can handle your intent
        //try in a another way ...
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:"+phoneNumber);
        smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", msg);
        infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(smsIntent, 0);
    }

    if (infos.size() <1) {
        //No Application can handle your intent
        Log.e("SendMessage","No Application can handle your SMS intent");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In kotlin following code works with number and custom message**

```
val defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(activity)  
            val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            sendIntent.type = "text/plain"
            sendIntent.putExtra("address", "sms:"+contactNumber)
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.share_msg_body))
            Timber.e("defaultSmsPackageName: "+defaultSmsPackageName)
            if (defaultSmsPackageName != null){ //Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose any app that support this intent.
                sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName)
                activity!!.startActivity(sendIntent)
            }
```