# An Intent that sends SMS message

Tags: android

this is going to be a newbie question, but I'm curious how Intent's ACTION_SENDTO works. The code is like this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_to_call);
String smsNumber = String.format("smsto: %s", textView.getText().toString());
EditText smsEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sms_message);
String sms = smsEditText.getText().toString();    
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse(smsNumber));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", sms);
```

I understand that:

- This is an implicit intent
- ACTION_SENDTO is the action of the intent
- setData takes in data of the intent

But whatever in putExtra, I guess what it does is putting in "extra" data? Immediate after running this intent, it takes me to a normal Messages app with number as smsNumber, and sms as content. My questions are:

1. How does the intent "know" smsNumber should be in the phone number section, and sms is in content section?
2. I also guess the name "sms_body" does affect the role of the data after it (aka sms is the content of message)?

Edit: I found an explanation for this. It should be in [Common Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Messaging)

Comment: The ```extra bundle``` is essentially a KeyValue store. The SMS App gets this bundle and looks for the value with key "sms_body". This behaviour (namely the key) must be hardwired into the App and not each SMS App will support it.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda understand what you're saying. The intent takes in the value as long as it is called "sms_body", my problem is I have not yet found an official document that specify these names (like sms_body) for the key part of putExtra. All I did was more like looking up people's codes and conclude that sms_body is necessary.

Comment: That is because there isn't an official documentation for all used intent keys. So, as an SMS App developer you are not obliged to built in handling this, though most of them do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "smsto:XXXXXXXXXX" in uri to give the phone number like in this example from the post :
[ACTION_SEND used to send sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788189/action-send-used-to-send-sms)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");   
startActivity(it);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I think my question is more about the putExtra("sms_body",...) part, I couldn't find any document that specify the strings names in putExtra argument, hence how is "sms_body" specified? Can I replace "sms_body" with "body"?

Comment: you can find the list of all extra per common intent at :
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common
Does it answer your question ?

Comment: The "sms_body" Extra is a string that all apps that handle sms sending look on, it's more and less a constant, you cannot change if without impacting the behavior of the app.